# MongoDB database backup from docker container in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

My docker container is running on port 27018. When I run following command from terminal, it's working correctly -

```
docker exec mongodb mongodump -u=Abhishek -p=abhishek --authenticationDatabase=testdb
```

But, when I run the same command from node.js, it's not working. Please have a look into my below code and help me debugging

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

const backupProcess = spawn('sudo docker exec mongodb mongodump', [
      `-u=Abhishek`,
      `-p=abhishek`,
      `--authenticationDatabase=testdb`
    ]);

    backupProcess.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('Error :: ', err);
    });

    backupProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
      if (code) {
        console.log(MessageType.warn, '\n Backup process exited with code ', code);
      } else if (signal) {
        console.log(MessageType.error, '\n Backup process was killed with signal ', signal);
      } else {
        console.log(MessageType.success, '\n Successfully backed-up the database ✅ ');
      }
    });
```

It's giving me following error -

```
Error ::  Error: spawn sudo docker exec mongodb mongodump ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn sudo docker exec mongodb mongodump',
  path: 'sudo docker exec mongodb mongodump',
  spawnargs: [
    '-u=Abhishek',
    '-p=abhishek',
    '--authenticationDatabase=testdb'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the command works? You try to export the entire database, however a user defined in database `testdb` may not have access to all databases, see [db.createRole](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/): *Except for roles created in the admin database, a role can only include privileges that apply to its database*

Comment: Yes, this command is working fine for me. I have only one database.

Comment: I think the issue is with spawn, I tried running other simple command like `docker ps` but this is also giving me same error. Can someone suggest me what will be best way to run docker commands inside nodejs script?

Comment: const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const testData = async()=>{



const dockerDeamon  = spawn('docker', ['ps','-a'
  ]);

dockerDeamon.stdout.on('data', data => {
        console.log(`${data}`);

    });

    dockerDeamon.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.log(`${data}`);

    });

    dockerDeamon.on('close', code => {
        console.log(`Docker Shell existed with status = ${code}`);

    });

};
testData();    //here I am able to execute docker ps -a command